# Bootstrap Sidebar Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a Bootstrap Theme with the Menu on the left sidebar. The problem is that I can't fix the content after the sidebar menu. Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

The content is placed into a row, in 4 span3 divs. How can I make this content to move right next to the sidebar nav?

```
<?php 
if ( !defined('ABSPATH')) exit; 
get_header(); 
?>

<?php if(is_front_page()): ?>
<div class="row wpeden-bs-services">
  <?php for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++){ ?>
    <div class="span3">
    <?php $tpid = (int)bleed_get_theme_opts('home_featured_page_'.$i);     $intropage=get_page($tpid); $introcontent = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($intropage->post_content),"p,br"); if (preg_match('/^.{1,80}\b/s', $introcontent, $match)) $introcontent = $match[0]; else $introcontent = substr($introcontent,0,80);  ?>
    <div class="about well">
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($intropage->ID); ?>"><?php bleed_thumb($intropage,array(500,300), array('class'=>'img')); ?></a>
      <div class="entry-content">
      <h2><?php echo $intropage->post_title; ?></h2>
      <p><?php echo $introcontent; ?></p>
      </div>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($intropage->ID); ?>" class="btn <?php echo bleed_get_theme_opts('button_style','btn-info'); ?> btn-block">View details</a>
    </div>  
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <!-- /.span4 -->
    <?php get_template_part('homepage','category'); ?>

   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div>
   </div>          

   </div><!-- /.span4 -->

   <?php endif; ?> 
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: This is the screenshot of the problem. Thanks for helping! http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu7PX.png

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net example and post the link? You'll need to exclude the PHP calls.  View the source of your page and post the mark-up from there

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EWP32/6/
I tried to do something, not sure if that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly it looks like you need to nest your rows.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        side bar here
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
        nested content goes here
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="span3"></div>
            <div class="span3"></div>
            <div class="span3"></div>
            <div class="span3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have this site on a web hosting somewhere? do you have a url?

Answer (score 0):

This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.

Make sure to keep all page content within the #page-content-wrapper.

http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/